# Why HTML elements are not displayed one below the other when I center them with Flexbox and their parent element is <body>?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center, vertical-alignment

I came across a situation that I don't really understand. I wanted to center two elements and after reading the article below, I decided to use flexbox to do that.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/

I applied "display: flex" and "justify-content: center" to the parent element which in my case is .

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
    <div>This is a paragraph</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

After this, my page looks as in the picture below:
[image: Output]

Taking into account that HTML elements should be positioned one below another, I don't understand why it's not happening in my case. The  is positioned above the  element. If I remove the CSS part, their vertical order gets back to normal -  above the .

What is doing the CSS part so that the natural vertical order of the elements is ignored?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The default value of `flex-direction` is `row`, whereas you want `column`:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > * {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the title</h1>
<div>This is a paragraph</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The default value for `flex-direction` is `row`.

The elements are *not* in a reversed order, they are **side-by-side** (and centred horizontally).

The default margins on the elements just means that the text inside the `p` appears higher than the text inside the `h1`.

You can see this by setting an outline on the elements (or by clicking the *flex* button next to the body element in the DOM inspector in your browser's developer tools).

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#container > * {
    outline: dotted blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<h1>This is the title</h1>
    <div>This is a paragraph</div>
</div>
```

Set `flex-direction` to `column` to arrange them in a column.